# bypassing the space problem when writing the function system() in a cmd to a certain path with space in C

Tags: c, windows, cmd

```
system("start 'C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe'");
system("start C:/Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2019/Photoshop.exe");
system("start C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe");
```

I tried all of these to get into the vector/path but nothing seems to be working if i execute it.

I TRIED THIS TOO:

```
system("start 'C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CC 2019\\Photoshop.exe'");
```

Comment: It would be a very good idea for the future to run a command line first in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window before using it in code of a C application. And it would be good to read the documentation of a command before using this command which can be done in this case with running in a command prompt window `start /?` and read the output help.

Comment: It would be also good to read once the Microsoft article about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file). It is described by Microsoft that on Windows the directory separator is ``\`` and not `/` as on Linux or Mac. Windows kernel usually corrects `/` in a file/folder string to ``\`` before passing the string to the file I/O function, but the usage of `/` instead of ``\`` can nevertheless result in an unexpected behavior, for example `for %I in (C:/Windows/*.exe) do @echo %I` versus `for %I in (C:\Windows\*.exe) do @echo %I`.

Comment: So with taking into account that the backslash character is the directory separator on Windows, and a file/folder string containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` must be enclosed in double quotes as explained by help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window, and that command `start` interprets first double quoted string as window title, and also C string syntax, the working code is (untested) `system("start \"\" \"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CC 2019\\Photoshop.exe\"");`.

Comment: You could also avoid using start. An executable can be launched without it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are using Windows, you didn't mention this.

On Windows there are many places where forward slashes are accepted as well as backslashes to separate directory names in paths. Exceptions include the command `del` (built-in of `cmd`) IIRC.

To escape an argument that contains spaces you need quotation marks `"`.

To include a quotation mark in a C string you need to escape it with a backslash.

Unfortunately I don't have a Windows system at hand, so this might contain an error. Please try this:

```
system("start \"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe\"");
```

---

**EDIT**

At work I *have to* use a Windows system, and indeed the proposal above had an error. Since `start` can set the title of the `cmd` window it will use its first non-option argument as such. Only the second non-option argument will be the program to launch.

So this should work:

```
system("start \"\" \"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe\"");
```